# What's the best way to invoke clojure worker threads on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, clojure

I'm currently just running the task through the scheduler.  It runs for several minutes.  I have no reason to think it is being shut down for running too long, but I'm wondering if it should be a worker thread instead.

How would I start a clojure process on a worker thread?  Is it as simple as tweaking the ProcFile and the scheduler command?

My ProcFile:

web: lein with-profile production trampoline run -m webhook.server

My App:
- Once per hour, fetch data into Heroku db via a scheduled web service call to another server.
- On demand, a ring-based web service serves JSON data to another process elsewhere on the web.

Comment: What do you mean by "Worker Threads?" Are you referring to Herouku Worker dyno types, or Clojure threading (i.e. Agents)?

Comment: I should have been more specific: Heroku Worker dynos

Comment: Can you provide your Proc file contents and a sketch of your Clojure app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you could create a Heroku "Worker" dyno that starts a plain old Java thread. For example, you could have a Clojure application with a `-main` function that uses concurrency, i.e.

```lisp
(defn -main [&args]
  (doseq [res (map deref [(future "task 1")
                          (future "task 2")
                          (future "task 3"])]
    (save-results res)))
```

Where `save-results` is an imaginary function that saves your worker results somewhere, sends an email, whatever.

Note that is probably a better way to do this, i.e. with [Agents](http://clojure.org/agents) or one of the Clojure scheduling libraries listed at the [Clojure Toolbox](http://www.clojure-toolbox.com/) (i.e. Quartzite). My example is a very simple (naive?) example that proves concurrency in a Heroku worker dyno.

See here for more discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/xQs6MqD3680

Also, I found [quite](http://heyman.info/2012/dec/6/heroku-multiple-processes-single-dyno-with-foreman/) [a few](http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/01-more-concurrency-on-a-single-heroku-dyno-with-the-new-celadon-cedar-stack/) blog posts / articles out there about running multiple threads on a single Heroku dyno. It limits you to something like 255 threads per dyno.

**Update** I created an proof-of-concept for the above:

https://github.com/noahlz/worker-sample

Comment: regarding multiple threads on a single dyno, the Unicorn technique is configured directly in Unicorn, which is for Ruby. I'm not sure how you can do this with Clojure and specify multiple threads.

Comment: Please restate the question.

Comment: You linked to an article about configuring multiple threads in Unicorn, but this technique does not apply to Clojure as far as I can tell. It would be interesting to see advice on how to use multiple threads on a single dyno in Clojure, not Ruby.

Comment: See my answer. Each of those `(future)` functions executes in a separate thread. You could also do something like `(Thread. #(do (println "In thread " (.getName (.currentThread Thread)))))` in your dyno.